# jsp page name that sent xmlhttprequest

Tags: jsp, url, xmlhttprequest, request

I have an web application which contains some jsp files as http services and main page contains some xmlhttprequests.
I want to make the response of the jsp files to the calls come from the main page only, I do not want users to calling to the jsp directly.

I am thinking in checking the page url which sent the request. If it is in the same server then pass or not but I don't know how to get the url of that page.

Any help in doing that or another idea?

Comment: to get the URL of the calling page you may use 'referer', if that's what you want like this:
String referer = request.getHeader("Referer ");

Comment: Exactly, Thank you too much